# Visual Studio 2012 Modernappstyle Editable Combobox c#

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, combobox, visual-studio-2012

Using Visual Studio 2012 C# (Template: Windows Store -> Blank App (XAML))

I want to create a ComboBox in a modernstyled app in which i also can enter text with the keyboard (like adressbar in browsers/explorers).

When i create a ComboBox and tap/click it i only can select the Item (if items added) but never can get a keyboard to show up. Creating an extra textbox won't solve the problem, because i want also the solutions you normaly get when you type something in a ComboBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no option for combo box in VS 2012 express edition. instead you can use the ListBox or ListPicker both serve the purpose. for details visit http://wpftutorial.net/ListBoxItemsArrange.html